# Gruntfile fails with Warning: Task "default" not found

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, long-running-processes

1. this is my gruntfile.
2. i run $ grunt default
3. actuall i want to up my index.html on some port and want it to open in chrom directly

   ```
     module.exports = function(grunt) {
     grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
       server: {
         options: {
           port: 9001,
           base: {
             path: 'Dev',
             options: {
               index: 'index.html',
               maxAge: 300000
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
      open: {
       delayed: {
         path: 'http://localhost:9001'
         app: 'Google Chrome'
         options: {
           openOn: 'serverListening'
         }
       }
     }     
     });
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'open']);
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the task:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
```